# Unexpected console output for wstring literal and console input concatenation

Tags: c++, clion

Platform: Win 10 64 bit
IDE: CLION 2022.2.3
Toolchain: VS 2022 Community Toolset v17.0 (CMAKE 3.23.2)
Build Tool ninja.exe
C++ compiler: cl.exe

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
    
int main() {
    std::wstring test1 = L"Hällo, ";
    std::wstring test2;
    
    std::cout << "Eingabe:" << std::endl;
    std::wcin >> test2;
    std::wcout << test1.append(test2);
}
```

User Input:

```cpp
Hälp!
```

Console Output:

```cpp
H├ñllo, Hälp!
```

I'm at the end of my wits here. I'm currently in the process of learning C++, and I'm dealing with some encoding problems. I have set both my file and console encoding to UTF-8. I am using wstring which should support umlauts. But for whatever reason I get a wrong output. I don't know where things go wrong.

My initial goal was to read in a txt file and count the number of characters per line and in total. I noticed, that I got a wrong count. For every ä, ö or ü my length() for the line would be off by 1 byte per Umlaut. So for

```cpp
std::wchar text = L"äbc";
cout << text.length();
```

I would get:

```cpp
4
```

Which struck me odd. Because I used wchar, and text.length() should have given me the number of wchar_t characters in my String, if I'm not mistaken.
When I try:

```cpp
std::wchar text;
std::wcin >> text;
cout << text.length();
```

With the user input:

```cpp
äbc
```

I would get the correct result of:

```cpp
3
```

I am sincerely at the end of my wits. I don't know what causes those encoding errors. I would appreciate any help.

PS. I also tested the same code in Visual Studio, and I got the same unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Argh. Alas, the problem is with Windows. Over the years their remains only _**one way**_ to guarantee proper Unicode I/O with the Windows Console/Terminal: `ReadConsoleW()` and `WriteConsoleW()`. I have actually written a library just for it: https://github.com/Duthomhas/utf8_console . Remember, I/O with the Windows Console/Terminal is limited to the Unicode BMP, if that matters. This is a limitation of the Console/Terminal. If you redirect a file through the stdin/stdout/stderr it has no such limitation.

Comment: Oh, BTW, C++ says _don’t mix wide and narrow I/O to the terminal_. Once you use one, you aren’t supposed to be able to use the other. Often in practice it isn’t a problem, but often enough it is, because the magic hamsters spinning the wheels underneath get annoyed.

Comment: @Dúthomhas I tried what you suggested, but it broke it even more. Now I got `HÃ¤llo, H?lp!` as an output.